# user validation for login

Tags: android, android-sqlite

am making an application. There is a login page on which the user enters username in the edittext field. That is then passed to a function in my databasehelper class which checks the username against the entries in the table in which all the username reside.

Here is the function i wrote for the validation in my databasehelper class:

```
public String verify_user(String is_user)
{
    String verify = " ";
    String check = " ";
    SQLiteDatabase fg = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = fg.query(Login_Table, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    int iuser = c.getColumnIndex(colUsername);
    for(c.moveToFirst() ; !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        verify = c.getString(iuser);
        if(is_user == verify)
        {
            check = "Valid User!";
        }
        else
        {
            check = "Not Valid User!";
        }
    }
    return check;

}
```

is_user is coming from the .xml layout file in which user enters username... when i debugged i found a strange behavior. Although in the condition is_user and verify have same values at a point but still else is executed. so me knowing the user is valid this code says Not Valid User! . Kindly guide me through. Thank You!

From a new suggestion:

```
String check = " ";
    SQLiteDatabase fg = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] args = new String[1];
    args[0] = is_user;
    Cursor c = fg.query(Login_Table, null, colUsername + " = ?", args, null, null, null);
    int iuser = c.getColumnIndex(colUsername);
    if(is_user.equals(c.getString(iuser)))
    {
        check = "Valid User!";
    }
    return check;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you compare Strings by using `equals()`, not `==`

```
if(is_user.equals(verify))
```

Also you don't need to loop through all users. Just add a condition in your query instead. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more info.

*EDIT*: the good query would be:

```
String[] args = new String[1];
args[0] = is_user;
Cursor c = fg.query(Login_Table, null, colUsername + " = ?", args, null, null, null);
```

Always use arguments, never concatenate like `colUsername+"="+is_user`, this is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: can u please specify the query for cursor here?? am trying to make the comparison with username!

Comment: would it be Cursor c = fg.query(Login_Table, colUsername, colUsername+"="+is_user, null, null, null, null) ??

Comment: ahhh i get it. eclipse says that i need to change that colusername from string to string[]. why is that??

Comment: where in my class static  final String colUsername="Username";

Comment: You can just put `null` there to select all columns. I've updated the answer.

Comment: can u please acknowledge my new code? if its right? i have updated question :)

Comment: it says cursorindexoutofbound exception now! just checked my logcat!

Comment: If you're selecting only the user in question, then the Cursor can be 0 or 1 in length (c.getCount()). If 0, it's not a valid user, if 1 it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.equals(...).

if(is_user.equals(verify)){
...
```